# Change <li> class to active when page is loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I'm having a hard time to make `<li>` class to active when page is loaded. Here's my scenario I copied a sample Dropdown in a certain website to integrate it in my website. I'm using C# Asp.Net

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    @Html.Partial("_HeaderPartial")
</div>
<!--SIDEBAR Navigation-->
<aside id="menu">
// The Dropdown       
        @Html.Partial("_SidebarPartial")

</aside>
<div id="wrapper">

        @RenderBody()

    <footer class="footer">
        @Html.Partial("_FooterPartial")
    </footer>
</div>
<div id="right-sidebar" class="animated fadeInRight">
    @Html.Partial("_RightSidebarPartial")
</div>
</body>
```

**_SidebarPartial**

```
 <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"> <span class="nav-label">Dashboard</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Analytics", "Home")"> <span class="nav-label">Analytics</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">Interface</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("PanelDesign", "Home")">Panels design</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Typography", "Home")">Typography</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Buttons", "Interface")">Colors &amp; Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Components", "Interface")">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Alerts", "Interface")">Alerts</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Modals", "Interface")">Modals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">App views</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contacts", "AppViews")">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Projects", "AppViews")">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ProjectDetail", "AppViews")">Project detail</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("AppPlans", "AppViews")">App plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SocialBoard", "AppViews")">Social board</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">Charts</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("", "")">ChartJs</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("", "")">Flot charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("", "")">Inline graphs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">Box transitions</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("", "")"><span class="label label-success pull-right">Start</span> Overview </a>  </li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("", "")">Columns from up</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Is it always the same `<li>` element that you want expanded?

Comment: @BojanB The main `<li>` only

Comment: If the main `<li>` is always the same element, then why not set the class in the source code of the Partial? However if the `<li>` element changes depending on the page you are on, then I would add the `id` attribute to the `<li>` elements and then add a jquery function with (`document.getElementById`) which would add the active class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, here is a small example with an `id` attribute on the list:

```
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li id="interfaces">
        <a href="#"><span class="nav-label">Interface</span><span class="fa arrow"></span> </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("PanelDesign", "Home")">Panels design</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Typography", "Home")">Typography</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Buttons", "Interface")">Colors &amp; Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Components", "Interface")">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Alerts", "Interface")">Alerts</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Modals", "Interface")">Modals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then you could add the following line to the `document.ready` function:

```
$("#interfaces").attr("class", "active");
```

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("interfaces").attr("class", "active");` I used `$("#interfaces").attr("class", "active");` caused when I use `document.getElementById` i get an error **attr is not a function**

Comment: @FrostyPinky Ok, but it is working with `$("#interfaces")`? If so, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This will also help you

just write the following code inside document.ready function

```
$('#interfaces').addClass('active');
```

Cheers